# Use dynamic path for assets - Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite

I'm using dynamic paths/src routes for images into my Nuxt project.

I import them from an independent script:

*{icon: '../assets/images/energy.svg'}*

As it doesn't work for dev mode rendering, I've identified that Nuxt (or Vite) copy all my assets into a *_nuxt* folder, so I tried to modified my paths like:

*/_nuxt/assets/images/energy.svg*

with this try, it starts to work well. But when I tried to deploy the page with *generate comand* it comes wrong again. This time I found that *Nuxt Generate* in adition to copying my assets into the *_nuxt* folder, added a random numeric suffix to the image name, like this:

*/_nuxt/assets/images/energy.1234.svg*

Trying to know how it works I tried to deploy in server mode and found that its behavior changed. This time it doesn't add the suffix into the image name. It could be a 'good' way to solve this issue, but I need, in this case, to make my deploy as a static side.

Is it there any way to config this behavior or a 'correct' way to use the dynamic path for my assets?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the path to `~/assets/path/to/img`

See: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets#assets-directory